# Understanding Fat Content on Nutrition Labels

Tags: nutrition, fat

For most foods that contain fat you'll see Total Fat content and Saturated, Trans Fat, Polyunsaturated, and Monounsaturated fats listed below that.  Sometimes the amounts don't always add up.  Total Fat could be 12g, Saturated Fat at 7g, and Trans Fat at 0g so there's 5g of fat unaccounted for.  Can one assume the remaining fat is some kind of unsaturated fat?  Are there "neutral" fats that aren't exactly saturated or unsaturated?

Comment: Questions regarding nutrition unrelated to exercises are considered to be off-topic according to the [faq]. As such, I am closing your question. However, you are welcome to edit your question and rewrite it specifically so that it fits within the scope outlined and defined by the [faq]. If it is fitting, the question can be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

The other two kinds of fats are [polyunsaturated fats](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/GettingHealthy/FatsAndOils/Fats101/Polyunsaturated-Fats_UCM_301461_Article.jsp) and [monounsaturated fats](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/GettingHealthy/FatsAndOils/Fats101/Monounsaturated-Fats_UCM_301460_Article.jsp).  They are widely agreed to be the 'good' fats.

This is a slight misnomer because you definitely need a decent amount of saturated fat (it makes up every nerve ending in your body), but you get the idea!

Comment: Good to know that saturated fat is okay [in moderation I'm sure].